# Как правильно сделать выдвижное меню. Android

Tags: java, android, menu, case

У меня есть `toolbar`, куда я добавляю элементы с помощью `MenuItem`, в файле хранятся иконки и айдишники. И меня интересует, как можно будет к одной из иконок (например к икноке с id - `menu_filter`) всплывающее меню.

**Код**:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_filter:
            Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Не могли бы написать реализацию на выдвижное меню в кейсе (`case R.id.menu_filter:...`) Буду благодарен, а то уже давольно долго пытаюсь сам это сделать, но ничего не выходит.

**MenuItem**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".controllers.FeedActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        android:title="@string/menu_filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

Comment: Я в чате вам написал, что в вашем случае надо использовать вложенные меню (sub menu)

Comment: @metalurgus не могу понять как это делается. Еще не делал так. Не могли бы объяснить.

Comment: Вы заранее знаете, какие элементы должны быть в подменю?

Comment: @metalurgus Да знаю. я дополнил еще код в вопросе.

Comment: @metalurgus или я что-то путаю?

Comment: зайдите в чат, и посмотрите

Comment: Используйте PopupMenu